# Check if site redirects to https using ruby

Tags: ruby, https

For my latest project, I am using the PageSpeed Insights API from google. One of the flaws in the request is that if the URL redirects to https the score portion from the result (conveniently the only part I am looking for) returns null.

Looking for some way of checking if a site redirects to https, searching for an answer has led to muddied results in Google due to keyword overlap.

Comment: You can do a get request to the url and check if the status is 3XX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection). Is this what you want?

Comment: It might also be easier to just ensure **all links specify https, not http** as the schema. Assuming your true problem is the existence of HTTP links, not the existence of the redirect.